# How to add column headers into an Excel sheet programmatically?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have an excel sheet (File1.xls). Before processing the File1.xls data, I need to add Column headers into it or create a new excel file (File2.xls) with column headers and copy File1.xls data into it.

Currently I am using OleDbConnection to read data from the excel sheet and loading it into a Datatable using **OleDbCommand**, **OleDbDataAdapter**. But I couldn't find any way to add column headers into an excel file.

Thanks in advance for the solution?

Answer (score 1):

U need to use a third party libary like [ExcelLibary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) supports .xls or [Epplus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) supports .xlsx. Or you can [COM Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which needs excel installed.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use samples that provided by you